# Correct usage of $mysqli->real_escape_string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-injection

When I call `$mysqli->real_escape_string($str)`, I get back a safe string that I can use in a query. It has all special symbols that can lead to SQL Injection Attack escaped.

My question is - what is the correct way to use it in a query later? Do I single quote or double quote this safe string?

For example,

```
$safe_title = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['safe_title']);
```

Now do I do this:

```
$r = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title='$safe_title'");
```

Or this:

```
$r = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title="'.$safe_title.'"');
```

Sometimes I do one, sometimes I do the other, but this one time when I did one of these and typed a bunch of garbage in input, I got an SQL query error somehow. I realized I'm doing it wrong and all my code is probably vulnerable. That's why I'm asking this question here.

Comment: Don't use real_escape_string. Better read about prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @dragon - they're not - look carefully - one uses single quotes - the other uses double quotes!

Comment: @JordiKroon Thanks I never heard of that.  Checking it out. Can you quickly comment why that is better? Like high level overview.

Comment: as far as mysql is concerned the passed string(querry) is identical

Comment: While you're at it, take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Answer (score 1):

You would do this:
    `$r = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title='$safe_title'");`

But as @JordiKroon pointed out prepared statements are preferred.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $safe_title);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    foreach ($row as $r)
    {
        print "$r ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```